# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf' But the TensorFlow v2.3 is already installed

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to import some regularizers, with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

# importing regularizers
from tf.keras.regularizers import l2, activity_l2
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8996/2415362791.py in <module>
      4 from tensorflow import keras
      5 # importing regularisers
----> 6 from tf.keras.regularizers import l2, activity_l2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'
```

However, I've already installed TensorFlow, and I can build neural networks, with several layers,  without any error showing up...
I'm using Anaconda v2.1, Jupyter Notebooks v6.4.3.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Since you've already imported keras in line 4, why not just do `from keras.regularizers import l2, activity_l2`?

Comment: @TCArlen I'm following "Deep Learning with 
TensorFlow 2 and Keras
Second Edition", and it seems that the book is already outdated. 

According to TensorFlow official tutorials, here's how to import and use regularization:

"from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import L2"

and then inside the keras.layer, use:
kernel_regularizer=L2(0.01).

Comment: Even if you `import tensorflow as tf`, you always have to use `tensorflow` in the other imports, not`tf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tensorflow.keras.regularizers` instead of `tf.keras.regularizers` as below:

`from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2` (to import specific regularizers)

or

`from tensorflow.keras import regularizers` (to use and import all other regularizers.)

`activity_l2` is deleted and is equal to `l2`. Find the related [github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5870) reference  here.